# Custom CRS WKT definition error

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am doing a project using Europa Mosaics and QGIS. I'm trying to find a Geodetic CRS for the mosaics (the embedded CRS is Cartesian). I found a bunch on http://voparis-vespa-crs.obspm.fr:8080/web/ (a database compiled and maintained by the IAU and USGS) but whenever I try the definitions, I get an error saying the definition is invalid. I've even tried typing the definitions into the parameters box verbatim rather than copying and pasting. I manually changed the cases and indentation after pasting it, but I got a similar error. Is there something else I can try? I don't think the definitions themselves are incorrect but I know nothing about WKT definitions.

Comment: If you haven't tried yet, copy the definition to a text file and remove all carriage returns. That is, try to make it a single line. If that doesn't work, hmm, I'd start removing objects that aren't strictly needed (remark, anchor, maybe even ID, but you'd have to be careful to make sure the [] still align. I don't use QGIS so I'm sorry that I can't help more.